# What do CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN, CF_EXTERN_C_END and CF_EXPORT do?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Out of curiosity I landed on Apple's **CFCalendar.h** and found some interesting syntax that I have never seen before. A google search did not help explain to me what is going on here. I notice that the syntax used to declare the functions is written in C.

The header file begins with:

```
CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED
CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN
```

It then has a bunch of these CF_EXPORT items:

```
CF_EXPORT
CFLocaleRef CFCalendarCopyLocale(CFCalendarRef calendar);

CF_EXPORT
void CFCalendarSetLocale(CFCalendarRef calendar, CFLocaleRef locale);

CF_EXPORT
CFTimeZoneRef CFCalendarCopyTimeZone(CFCalendarRef calendar);
```

It then finally ends with this:

```
CF_EXTERN_C_END
CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_DISABLED
```

Comment: It depends what they are defined to do.  If you are in Xcode then you can *Jump To Definition* to see.

Comment: I suspect they're defined to the usual `extern "C" {` and `}`.

Comment: Xcode doesn't find anything using *Jump to Definition*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on both Mac OS and iOS `CF_EXPORT` is defined as `#define CF_EXPORT extern`. If you don't know already `extern` tells the compiler that the symbol is external (one that can be linked from other code files).

the `CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN` `CF_EXTERN_C_END` and end macros are there for C++ (`defined(__cplusplus)`) they are defined as nothing otherwise.

`CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED` and `CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_DISABLED` simply maps to clang pragmas to turn on and off implicit bridging of corefoundation to ARC.

here are the relevant parts of CFBase.h:

```
#ifndef CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED
#if __has_feature(arc_cf_code_audited)
#define CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED _Pragma("clang arc_cf_code_audited begin")
#else
#define CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED
#endif
#endif

#ifndef CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_DISABLED
#if __has_feature(arc_cf_code_audited)
#define CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_DISABLED _Pragma("clang arc_cf_code_audited end")
#else
#define CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_DISABLED
#endif
#endif

#if !defined(CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN)
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN extern "C" {
#define CF_EXTERN_C_END   }
#else
#define CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN
#define CF_EXTERN_C_END
#endif
#endif

#if !defined(CF_EXPORT)
#if defined(CF_BUILDING_CF) && defined(__cplusplus)
#define CF_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
#elif defined(CF_BUILDING_CF) && !defined(__cplusplus)
#define CF_EXPORT extern __declspec(dllexport) 
#elif defined(__cplusplus)
#define CF_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) 
#else
#define CF_EXPORT extern __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
#endif

#else
#define CF_EXPORT extern
#endif
```